# Trouble booting SeaGate's "SeaTools Bootable" on a Dell laptop

Tags: hard-drive, boot, liveusb

W11; Dell Latitude.

I'm having difficulty using SeaGate's "[SeaTools Bootable](https://www.seagate.com/manuals/software/seatools-bootable/)" software. I'm able to put it onto an USB-Drive as per the instructions. But when I try and boot it the sequence of pictures seen in this [Dropbox share-link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/7adh1tuotlgk0zwh8guko/h?rlkey=kkp5p240ddgw4mw0xl0n47an7&dl=0) occurs.

Picture 1 shows my "Boot Configuration" screen in my BIOS. Note that I turned "Secure Boot" off after taking that picture; "Secure Boot" was initially preventing me from even booting the USB-Drive.

Picture 2 shows the menu-screen I'm greeted with after booting up the USB-Drive.

Picture 3 is what is presented to me if I choose the rightmost option of the menu seen in picture 2. The title of the option is something like "SeaGate Command-Line Tools".

Picures 4-7 show the sequence it presents to me if I choose either the leftmost option or the central option of the menu seen in picture 2--both of those two options seem to run exactly the same sequence. The title of the leftmost option is "Boot SeaTools X", and I think the title of the central option is just "Boot SeaTools". Pressing enter at picture 7 just adds a new line with the current time and date.

Picture 8 is what it shows when I use "Ctrl+Alt+Del" to shut the PC down when at the screen of picture 7.

I've read the manual for the software and there's nothing in it that seems to pertain to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the SeaTools online documentation it seems that the only thing SeaTools does is reading SMART parameters, starting tests and deleting storage.

I don't see any (unique) feature that justifies enclosing their software into a separate linux system.

To read SMART parameters or start tests just use the open source software smartmontools that comes with lots of linux distributions that run from a USB pen drive.
Currently (29.3.2024) distros such as GParted, SystemRescueCD and Knoppix come with smartmontools.

After booting your distro run `lsblk` to get information about your block (disk) devices.
Start a command prompt an run `sudo smartctl -i  /dev/sdX`
Replace the letter X in the command above by the letter of your disk.
You will be shown manufacturer, size, disk model and serial number.

Insert a second USB pen drive with some space left in a second USB slot, mount the pen drive and run `sudo smartctl -a  /dev/sdX > myreport.txt`. That command redirects the output of smartmontools into the file `myreport.txt`. The command `pwd` (present working directory` shows you where that file was written to.

You can as well replace myreport.txt by a complete path leading to a directory on your second USB pen drive.
As the report is looking ugly on a windows system becausing line ends differ from unix systems use a software like the free and open source software Notepad++ to format the line ends to the style Microft Windows uses.